# What is the real danger of allowing SMB 1 client to access files on legacy device (which is not SMB 2 capable) on the local network?

Tags: windows-10, networking, samba, smb

I have an old device which is not SMB 2 capable. Much has been written about danger of using SMB1 (eg. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/stop-using-smb1/ba-p/425858). I would like to access files on this device from current Windows 10 client. Windows 10 still allows to enable SMB1 through checkbox "SMB 1.0/CIFS client" in "Turn Windows features on or off" in Control Panel. Is there any real danger for Windows 10 client by doing so?

Comment: Many older devices have opensource firmware support, and if it's a network device, check out OpenWrt [preferable] and DD-WRT.

Answer (score 3):

If the old device server is not accessible from the internet and is not used
for internet surfing, it's as secure as the rest of your local network.

In order for it to be infected, another device from the LAN must be infected first,
then propagate the infection. I think that at this point the whole question
of SMBv1 vulnerability becomes somewhat mute.

SMBv1 vulnerability is dangerous for larger networks. A modest home LAN should
avoid SMBv1, but an old device disconnected from the internet cannot be used
as an entry-point by an attacker.

For more information, see :

- Microsoft's advisory
  [Stop using SMB1](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/stop-using-smb1/ba-p/425858)
- [What’s the Problem with SMB 1, and Should You Worry About SMB 2 and 3?](https://securityboulevard.com/2018/12/whats-the-problem-with-smb-1-and-should-you-worry-about-smb-2-and-3/)

Comment: The server and the client would have to offline since WannaCry vulnerability was a worm and would infect any device it found and encrypt ALL accessible drives.  Enabling SMBv1 in 2021 is incredible dangerous and shouldn’t be done.